# How to debug lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Invalid expression error

Tags: python, xml, debugging, xslt, lxml

I'm trying to find out why lxml cannot parse an XSL document which consists of a "root" document with various `xml:include`s. I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "s.py", line 10, in <module>
  xslt = ET.XSLT(ET.parse(d))
File "xslt.pxi", line 409, in lxml.etree.XSLT.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:151978)
lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Invalid expression
```

That tells me where in the lxml source the error is, but *is there a way to get more through lxml about where in the xsl the error is*, or should I be using a different method? I'm trying to provide a service that accepts XSL documents, so I don't have access to an XML editor to debug manually. What I would like to do though is give feedback about why a transformation didn't succeed.

Comment: did you go anywhere about this issue?

Comment: Sorry, @gmas80, I've moved on and lost most of the context for this. I did a quick search and found [this](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#errors-and-messages).

Comment: The link from the previous comment is quite a good answer to the question and should be made as one.

Comment: The link in the comment is only good for successful runs -- it's useless for debugging exceptions.

Comment: @EthanFurman that's not the reason that it's a bad answer to this question, but it is a bad answer.

Comment: lxml class XSLT returns object that has variable .Error_log with detailed location and error messages for all transform faults. See: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#errors-and-messages

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at the exception's properties, I see that it has an error_log, but for an xpath error (for example) the log only includes information about where *within* the xpath the error is, so it's not especially helpful. For the use-case I describe, having arbitrary users submitting XSLT, there's not a push-button approach. Instead, it would be probably be easiest to use a combination of schema validation and custom logic to find out where the error is and why it's an error for the purpose of reporting back to the user.