# How to find the exact line of error from python 3.6.5?

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

```
from lxml import etree
import os
import copy
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
XMLDoc = etree.parse(open('aa.xml'))
XSLDoc = etree.parse(open('aa.xsl'))
try:
    transform = etree.XSLT(XSLDoc)
except:
    for error in etree.XSLT.error_log:
        print(error.message, error.line)

v = '/person/name'
for Node in XMLDoc.xpath(v):
    m2 = copy.deepcopy(Node)
    m3 = etree.tostring(m2, method="xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8", with_tail=False)
    m3 = m3.decode("utf-8")
    dc = open('pq.xml', 'w')
    dc.write(str(m3))
    dc.close()
    xm = etree.parse(open('pq.xml'))
    q = transform(xm)
    print(q)
```

I have use lxml for transform our xml to another xml through xslt but i have one parsing error in our xslt.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anil\PTest\08\qqq.py", line 13, in <module>
    for error in etree.XSLT(XSLDoc).error_log:
  File "src\lxml\xslt.pxi", line 410, in lxml.etree.XSLT.__init__
lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Failed to compile predicate
```

Please suggest how to find exact problem in our xslt.

Comment: Same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285601/how-to-get-more-info-from-lxml-errors), but OP has not accepted the answer. You might want to check this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get more info from lxml errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285601/how-to-get-more-info-from-lxml-errors)

Answer (score 0):

XSLT should have a log attached to it, so you can do something like the following:

```
try:
    # Your Code
except:
    for error in YourXSLTObject.error_log:
        print(error.message, error.line)
```

Comment: i Have try to this but our problem is not resolved.                                  XSLDoc = etree.parse(open('test.xsl', encoding='utf-8'))


try:
    transform = etree.XSLT(XSLDoc)
except:
    for error in etree.XSLT(XSLDoc).error_log:
        print(error.message, error.line)
I think this is etree.XSLT transformation error. Please elaborate with one example if possible

Comment: I have edit my question with your comment. check and suggest.

Comment: It should be for error in transform, not etree.XSLT.error_log. You should also be trying the transform itself, not just the assignment of etree.XLST(XSLDoc)

Comment: I have edit the error log of my question and i don't understand what is actual problem. see and suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: 'q = transform(xm)' should be a part of your try statement.